# 3d orthogonal projection on a plane

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, projection

I have a point in 3d P(x,y,z) and a plane of view Ax+By+Cz+d=0 . A point in plane is E.Now i want to project that 3d point to that plane and get 2d coordinates of the projected point relative to the point E.

```
P(x,y,z) = 3d point which i want to project on the plane.
Plane Ax + By + Cz  + d  = 0 , so normal n = (A,B,C)
E(ex,ey,ez) = A point in plane ( eye pos of camera )
```

What i am doing right now is to get nearest point in plane from point P.then i subtract that point to E.I suspect that this is right ???

please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The closest point is along the normal to the plane.  So define a point Q that is offset from P along that normal.

```
Q = P - n*t
```

Then solve for t that puts Q in the plane:

```
dot(Q,n) + d = 0
dot(P-n*t,n) + d = 0
dot(P,n) - t*dot(n,n) = -d
t = (dot(P,n)+d)/dot(n,n)
```

Where dot((x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2)) = x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2

Comment: thanks Vaughn,ok,now i got the nearest point but i want to translate that point relative to E ( so,now E is origin ).I subtract the nearest point coords from E.Is it correct ??? let me know if u couldn't get my question properly ??

Comment: In your question you indicate wanting 2D coordinates.  That would require a 2D coordinate system to be established on the plane.  You say that E should be the origin, but what about the axes?

Comment: actually I wanted to shift origin point to E and make that plane new XY plane,so that both E and the new point will have same Z.may be i am missing something ?? and also how to create 2D coordinae system ???

Comment: you have to define an X and Y axis that lie in the plane.  You could pick one axis arbitrarily and pick the other axes such that it is perpendicular to the first.

Answer (score 0):

You get a point on the plane as `p0 = (0, 0, -d/C)`. I assume the normal has unit length.

The part of p in the same direction as n is  `dot(p-n0, n) * n + p0`, so the projection is `p - dot(p-p0,n)*n`.

If you want some coordinates on the plane, you have to provide a basis/coordinate system. Eg two linear independent vectors which span the plane. The coordinates depend on these basis vectors.